# create multiple NxM matrices

Tags: matrix, permutation, enumeration

I'm looking for a code which returns all combinations of NxM matrices consisting of only ones and zeros. Every row contains precisely one '1'. Every column consists of one or more '1'. If the rules for rows and columns are hard to program they may be left out since computational problem is not going to be an issue.

1 0 0
1 0 0
1 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 1

1 0 0
1 0 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 0 1 
etc. etc. etc.

Hopefully someone can help me out.
Cheers, Raymond